# How to compile Clang LibTooling programs under Bionic?

Tags: package-management, compiling, clang

I'm trying to port a project that uses Clang's LibTooling library from Arch to Ubuntu/Debian.
I have installed the `clang-10`, `llvm-10` and `libclang-10-dev` packages. The latter installs the necessary headers to `/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/clang/` (i.e. `usr/lib/llvm-10/include/clang/Tooling/Tooling.h`). However, trying to link a program that uses these headers results in various linking errors such as:

```
undefined reference to `clang::ast_matchers::internal::DynTypedMatcher::matches(clang::ast_type_traits::DynTypedNode const&, clang::ast_matchers::internal::ASTMatchFinder*, clang::ast_matchers::internal::BoundNodesTreeBuilder*) const'
```

Under Arch I can resolve this with `-lclang-cpp` but no such library exists under Ubuntu. Several posts on StackOverflow recommend linking to various other libraries, so I have als tried:

```
-lclangFrontendTool -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangSerialization -lclangCodeGen -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangAnalysis -lclangARCMigrate -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic
```

But that does not work either. Are the `libclang-*-dev` packages incomplete/broken? Am I missing yet another package? Or am I just linking against the wrong libraries?

Comment: You haven't shared your Ubuntu version however according to apt-file, libclang-cpp *does* exist on Ubuntu - as part of the `libclang-cpp10-dev` package for example: `libclang-cpp10-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/libclang-cpp.so`

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks, that solved it, I don't know how I missed that...

Comment: ... and I missed the "Bionic" right in the title - apologies for that

Comment: Thanks, I had the same error and adding -lclang-cpp resolved it.  Perhaps the ubuntu LLVM/Clang packages are not build using LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB and LLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB (see: https://llvm.org/docs/BuildingADistribution.html#options-for-reducing-size).